# Find records with missing associated records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a legacy database where I have two models as:

```
class Purchase
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  has_many :purchases
end
```

Now over time some of the `products` were deleted even though the associated `purchases` still exist in the database. Is there a way I can get the list of all `Purchases` for which the associated `products` were deleted from the rails console?

My `purchase` table references `product` and has a column `product_id`

Comment: Removed the [tag:ruby-on-rails-4] since the accepted answer is a [tag:ruby-on-rails-5] answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Purchase.left_outer_joins(:product).where(products: {id: nil})
```

Note rails 5 have [left_outer_joins](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html)

so here basically it will result all purchases who does not have associated product.

Comment: `purchases.product_id` is not `NULL` it just no longer references an existing product maybe you meant `product: {id: nil }`

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh sory it my mistake, thanks for correct me!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you nullify the purchases when you remove a product?

```
class Product
  has_many :purchases, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

Like that, all you have to do is query the purchases where product_id is null. Hope this helps!

EDIT:
If you're using this approach now, for updating the old records and making them consistent, you should do something like this:

```
Purchase.where.not(product_id: Product.select(:id).distinct).update_all(product_id: nil)
```

So like this it should work by now

Comment: I did that now, but I still have old records with missing associations.

Comment: @RonanLopes For your kind information map internally goes through loop which is not efficient. however this can also be done in sql query.

Comment: @Gabbar yeah, I'm aware of that... but since it's something that will be done only once, I don't think that's a problem...

Comment: @Gabbar is there a quicker way to obtain an array list of ids for that case without using map?

Comment: @RonanLopes Ofcourse! you can use `pluck`  like `Product.pluck(:id)`, this will fire sql query, instead of go through loop and the thing which can be done by sql query, why should we go through looping?

Comment: @Gabbar amazing... didn't know pluck method. Updated the answer... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @RonanLopes better than that would simply be `Purchase.where.not(product_id: Product.select(:id).distinct).update_all(product_id: nil)`. This keeps everything in SQL by creating a subquery

Comment: What's the difference between that and pluck? Shouldn't pluck do the same? updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: @RonanLopes `pluck` returns an `Array` and creates an in clause of `NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,...)` my recommendation uses a subquery like `NOT IN( SELECT id FROM products)` which means SQL handles the whole thing. This is extremely important when you have a lot of ids because a SQL statement can only have so many characters. The only thing not necessarily needed in my suggestion is the distinction since `id` will always be distinct but in other cases this too is useful

Comment: @engineersmnky awesome! Thanks for the explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6.1 added the `missing` wherechain. Now you can achieve the same as Anand's answer with `Purchase.where.missing(:products)`

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing